# Drupal 6 File Handling

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-fapi

I am handling file upload field in a form using Drupal 6 form APIs. The file field is marked as **required**.
I am doing all the right steps in order to save and rename files in proper locations.

upload form

```
$form = array();
....
$form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Upload photo'),
    '#size' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
...
```

form validate handler

```
$image_field = 'image';

if (isset($_FILES['files']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$image_field])) {
    $file = file_save_upload($image_field);
    if (!$file) {
        form_set_error($image_field, t('Error uploading file'));
        return;
    }
    $files_dir = file_directory_path();
    $contest_dir = 'contest';

    if(!file_exists($files_dir . '/' . $contest_dir) || !is_dir($files_dir . '/' . $contest_dir))
        mkdir($files_dir . '/' . $contest_dir);


    //HOW TO PASS $file OBJECT TO SUBMIT HANDLER
    $form_state['values'][$image_field] = $file;
    file_move($form_state['values'][$image_field], $files_dir."/" . $contest_dir . "/contest-". $values['email']. "-" . $file->filename);
}
else {
    form_set_error($image_field, 'Error uploading file.');
    return;
}
```

On submiting form

Form always reports an error `Upload photo field is required.` although files are getting uploaded. How to deal with this issue?

How to pass file information to submit handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your handler is wrong. You never should touch $_FILES or $_POST variables in drupal, instead you should only use the drupal tools. Said that, the implementation you should is like that:

```
function my_form_handler(&$form,&$form_state){/** VALIDATION FILE * */
 $extensions = 'jpeg jpg gif tiff';
 $size_limit = file_upload_max_size(); 
 $validators = array(
      'my_file_validate_extensions' => array($extensions),
      'my_file_validate_size' => array($size_limit),
  );

 $dest = file_directory_path();
 if ($file = file_save_upload('image', $validators, $dest)) {
  //at this point your file is uploaded, moved in the files folder and saved in the DB table files
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to use the filefield module and append it to a form, as described in:

[Drupal Imagfield/Filefield in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387305/drupal-imagfield-filefield-in-custom-form)

The question has a link to the solution:

http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/01/26/display-cck-filefield-or-imagefield-upload-widget-your-own-custom-form

Answer (score 1):

From the [Drupal 6 Form API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#file):

"Note: the #required property is not supported (setting it to true will always cause a validation error). Instead, you may want to use your own validation function to do checks on the $_FILES array with #required set to false. You will also have to add your own required asterisk if you would like one."

Old post, but I'm looking for something similar and figured I add that.